# Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in Android programming. I am using Android Studio 2.3 and when I create a new project then it opens the editor but doesn't show any files or anything. I am posting a screenshot. Please help me to find the source files.

[image]

Comment: Click on Project at the left side navigation.

Comment: At the bottom there is message that 'Gradle sync failed', so please post those logs

Comment: Please refer : https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just click on `Project` at the left side navigation.

[image]